# Can't connect to internet while connected to adb

Tags: eclipse, virtualbox, android-x86

I'm using virtualbox 4.1.2 and android x86 in a Windows 7 OS. I used Two PCNet Fast III, one for NAT and another for Host-Only Adapter. I was able to use the netcfg to up the two ethernet, I was able to get connected to adb, but I couldn't get to the internet on the android x86.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two network interfaces mess up routing. You should use only one interface with NAT, and forward appropriate port 5555 using VirtualBox's NAT port forwarding.

Now you'll be able to connect using "adb connect localhost:5555" or simply "adb connect".